# Polar coordinate in Cartesian

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

My book states one can write polar coordinates $(\hat{r}, \hat{\theta})$as $$\hat{r} = \cos \theta i + \sin \theta j$$

$$\hat{\theta} = -\sin \theta i + \cos\theta j$$

Can someone explain how $$\hat{\theta} = -\sin \theta i + \cos\theta j$$

Comment: $\hat \theta$ is orthogonal to $\hat r$ and points in the counterclockwise direction (the direction of positive increase of the variable $\theta$) at the point $(r,\theta)$.  Also, neither $\hat r$ nor $\hat \theta$ should have the $r$'s on the RHS.

Comment: @Bye_World, wait why is $\hat{\theta} \perp \hat{r}$?

Comment: Conceptually or are you asking for a proof?

Comment: @Bye_World, conceptually, i mean the proof is just taking the inner product...

Comment: @Bye_World, it's more like why is $\hat{\theta}$ defined this way.

Comment: Because $\hat \theta$ should point in the direction of increase of $\theta$.  But that's tangent to a circle.  And the tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radial vector to the point of tangency.  Thus $\hat \theta\ \bot\ \hat r$.

Comment: The question is unclear to me: if $(\hat{r},\hat{\theta})$ are polar *coordinates*, then $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ should be scalars. But they seems to be vectors (I interpret $(i,j)$ as the canonical basis of ${\mathbb R}^2$).

Comment: @Bye_World, In my head I am seeing one vector (which is $\hat{r}$), is $\hat{\theta}$ defined to be the orthogonal vector to $\hat{r}$ (I mean before even writing down the equations)

Comment: @Taladris, no I am just trying to write the basis of polar coordinates in cartesians.

Comment: Technically it's defined something more like $(\frac{\partial \vec r(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta})/\|\frac{\partial \vec r(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}\|$, but conceptually it's the vector orthogonal to $\hat r$ at $(r,\theta)$ that points in the direction of positive increase of $\theta$.

Comment: @Taladris $(\hat r,\hat \theta)$ is an ordered basis.  Both the vectors $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ *depend on the coordinates* $(r,\theta)$.

Comment: @Bye_World, strange question, but this choice isn't unique right? Looks we the book just went with the orthogonal frame.

Comment: Which choice? The unit vectors $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ are defined as $(\frac{\partial \vec r(r,\theta)}{\partial r})/\|\frac{\partial \vec r(r,\theta)}{\partial r}\|$ and $(\frac{\partial \vec r(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta})/\|\frac{\partial \vec r(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}\|$, respectively.

Comment: @ ferric duffe It (vectorially) says r lines are orthogonal to $\theta $ lines in a polar net.

Comment: @Bye_World, if you fix one, the other shouldn't be unique right? It is only if decide to stick with an orthogonal frame. Unless you are telling me they are defined to be orthogonal no matter what then I guess they have to be.

Comment: Using the definitions I give above, at a point $(r,\theta)$ there are unique vectors $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$.  You can also show from the definitions that those two vectors are orthogonal to one another (and they're clearly unit length).  Thus they give an orthonormal basis for the plane.

Comment: @Bye_World, [found the definitions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUoU0rpsD3Y) which I was looking for. That is $\hat{\theta}$ is defined to be the direction of increasing $\theta$. Now this question seemed silly.

Comment: That guy says almost exactly the same things I've said.  I guess it was the drawings that helped though.  Anyway, good to know you got it now! :)

Comment: @Bye_World, you did, but the presentation was like an introduction. My book does neither. Thank you